# How do I get a quick peak at a detached session in (gnu-)screen?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, session

Let's say I have a detached session in (gnu-)screen:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    3629.pts-0.confusion    (03/11/22 15:50:21) (Detached)
1 Sockets in /run/screen/S-root.
```

Is there a good way to get a quick peek at what's happening in that session with just a single command and immediately detach again?

I don't want to do the whole dance of `screen -r 3629.pts-0.confusion`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>. But rather just, something like:

```
$ screen <some option> 3629.pts-0.confusion | tail -n 2
confus@confusion:/mnt/d2# rsync -aHXAh --info=progress2 /some/dir /some/other/dir
         19.30G  10%    5.64MB/s    7:34:31  xfr#0, to-chk=66/321252)
$ # ... coninue about by usual business outside of screen ...
```

to see what's currently going on? That would be especially nice if you have a few sessions and could just checkup o them all `for x in session{1..10}; do screen <some option> $x | tail -n 5; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

Yes, you have a couple of options:

1. send the hardcopy command to the screen you want to check and tail the generated file
2. turn on logging for the windows you're interested in and tail the log file (I wouldn't do this unless you actually check them fairly frequently, like every minute or two).

#### TL;DR for option 1:

```
# In this example the third window/tab (number 2) has the title "test_title", and 
# "test_session" is the session name.

# Set the hardcopy output directory to /tmp (only needs to happen once per screen session):
screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopydir /tmp

# Output the last two lines of the third window (number 2):
screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy && tail -n2 /tmp/hardcopy.2 && rm /tmp/hardcopy.2
```

### Explanation and More Options

I'm going to do into detail on option 1 since it is most likely the route you want to take.

1. You will likely want to change the default screen directory for the screen session so that the hardcopy (and log if you decide to go that route) go where you expect them.  
   **Command:**

   ```
   # In this example the third window/tab (number 2) has the title "test_title", 
   # and "test_session" is the session name.
   #
   # Either of these commands will work, and you don't need to pass 
   # "-S test_session" if you only have one screen session and/or you don't
   # need to pass "-p title/number" if you only have one window in that session.

   screen -S test_session -p test_title -X chdir /tmp
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X chdir /tmp

   # If only 1 window in the session:
   screen -S test_session -X chdir /tmp
   # If only 1 session (with multiple windows):
   screen -p 2 -X chdir /tmp

   # Can also only change the directory for hardcopy, if preferred:
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopydir /tmp
   ```

   **Relevant screen man entries:**

   > **chdir** [*directory*]
   >
   > Change  the  current  directory  of screen to the specified directory or, if called without an argument, to your home directory (the value of the environment  variable $HOME).   All windows that are created by means of the "screen" command from within ".screenrc" or by means of "C-a : screen ..." or "C-a c" use this as their  default directory.   Without a chdir command, this would be the directory from which screen was invoked.  Hardcopy and log files are always written  to  the  window's  default directory, not the current directory of the process running in the window.  You can use this command multiple times in your .screenrc to start various windows in  different  default  directories,  but the last chdir value will affect all the windows
   > you create interactively.
   >
   > **hardcopydir** *directory*
   >
   > Defines  a  directory  where hardcopy files will be placed. If unset, hardcopys are dumped in screen's current working directory.
2. Send the hardcopy command to create a file with the window's current output:  
   **Command:**

   ```
   # In this example the third window/tab (number 2) has the title "test_title", 
   # and "test_session" is the session name.
   #
   # Same rules as above apply if you only have one session or only one window
   # in a session, so I'll only use the example where you provide the session
   # name and window number here.

   # Create a hardcopy with the default filename:
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy

   # Create a hardcopy with a designated filename (in this case "output.tmp"):
   # NOTE: in my testing, this will put the file in the default directory defined
   #       by "chdir" and will ignore the hardcopy directory defined by "hardcopydir"
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy output.tmp

   # Create a hardcopy with the default filename including more lines
   # than are currently shown in the window:
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy -h
   ```

   **Relevant screen man entry:**

   > **hardcopy** [**-h**] [*file*]
   >
   > Writes out the currently displayed image to the file *file*, or, if no  filename is specified, to  *hardcopy.n*  in the default directory, where *n* is the number of the current window.  This either appends or overwrites the  file if it exists.  See below.   If the option **-h** is specified, dump also the contents of the scrollback buffer.
3. Tail the file. This is pretty self-explanatory, but I'll list the commands just so you can see everything working together:  
   **Command:**

   ```
   # In this example the third window/tab (number 2) has the title "test_title", 
   # and "test_session" is the session name. It also assumes that you
   # changed screen's default directory or hardcopy directory to /tmp.
   #
   # Same rules as above apply if you only have one session or only one window
   # in a session, so I'll only use the example where you provide the session
   # name and window number here.

   # See the last 2 lines of window number 2 in session "test_session":
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy test.output && tail -n2 /tmp/test.output

   # Same as above but delete the file afterward (just in case it has sensitive 
   # information or something):
   screen -S test_session -p 2 -X hardcopy test.output && tail -n2 /tmp/test.output && rm /tmp/test.output
   ```

##### Other potentially relevant screen man entries

> **hardcopy_append** **on**|**off**
>
> If set to "on", screen will append to the "hardcopy.n" files created by the command "C-a h", otherwise these files are overwritten each time.  Default is `off'.

### References

- `screen` and `tail` man pages

Comment: Excellent answer